# Read environment variable when debugging in MonoDevelop

Tags: .net, linux, mono, monodevelop

Environment variables are retrieved via `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VAR_NAME")`

Using `export VAR_NAME=123` in bash doesn't work (above command returns null). Setting System.EnvironmentVariableTarget to either User, Machine or Process doesn't work.

Putting a shell script in /etc/profile.d/settings.sh with `export VAR_NAME=123` requires a restart which is unacceptable. I haven't been able to find a way to load changes either without restarting. Using `source /etc/profile.d/settings.sh` doesn't work. I also haven't tested if it actually works after a restart, because I'm not going to restart :)

Exporting the variable through MonoDevelop works, but is not an option since the settings are used across projects. I can't set environment variables for the solution.

There must be better ways. Any clues?

Edit1: Got it working when running the application inside bash. Now I can't debug anything in MonoDevelop, so I'd like to find a way for MonoDevelop to include the required variables without setting them in every project.

Edit2: Got pretty close in MonoDevelop by going to `Run -> Run With -> Custom Parameters` and adding the environment variables. They're still not applied when debugging though.

Edit3: Using Run With -> Custom Parameters was a dead end as it doesn't support running multiple projects within MonoDevelop. It simply won't allow adding any custom parameters if there's more than one startup project.

Comment: Maybe create a .sh script which exports the variables and runs the mono executable?

Comment: I wanted to be able to use debugging in MonoDevelop. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute MonoDevelop from bash. This way environment variables are available when debugging.